# Understanding Class Hierarchy & OOP as it relates to Arrays.asList type conversion issue

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, hierarchy, class-hierarchy

I'm studying the book Thinking in Java.
My question is why no there is no type conversion exception in this line:

```
List<Snow> snow4 = Arrays.<Snow>asList(new Light(), new Heavy());
```

even though the new `Light()` and `new Heavy()` are `Powder` type, in the following code sample from the book:

```
package com.yanbit.collection.basic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

class Snow {
}

class Powder extends Snow {
}

class Crusty extends Snow {

}

class Stush extends Snow {
}

class Light extends Powder{}

class Heavy extends Powder {
}

public class AsListInference {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // swith list<Snow>
    List<Snow> snow1 = Arrays.asList(new Powder(), new Crusty(),
        new Stush());
    // List<Snow> snow2 = Arrays.asList(new Light(), new Heavy());
    // type list<power>
    List<Snow> snow3=new ArrayList<Snow>();
    Collections.addAll(snow3, new Light(), new Heavy());// implict type
    List<Snow> snow4 = Arrays.<Snow> asList(new Light(), new Heavy());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is hierarchical. `Light` and `Heavy` are subclasses of `Powder`, but `Powder` is a subclass of `Snow`, so there is a direct cast from a `Light` or `Heavy` object to a `Snow` object.

You can perform a cast from a subclass to any of its parent classes (or implemented interfaces), hence why every reference type can be cast to `Object`.

Comment: List<Snow> snow2 = Arrays.asList(new Light(), new Heavy()); new Light() and new Heavy() is Power type Powder is a subclass of Snow why can not cast to Snow object

Answer (score 0):

This goes beyond Java programming.  Class Hierarchy is a basic concept that you'll need to understand in order to be successful at any Object Oriented Programming.

Essentially, you need to understand that the Light class inherits all of the properties & methods from the Powder class.   The Powder class inherits all of the properties & methods from the Snow class.  Therefore, the Light class, through inheritance, will also inherit all of the properties & methods of the Snow class.

When you declare the List object as able to hold any type of Snow object, you're allowing it to hold any instance of Snow as well as any instance of a sub-class of the Snow.  This holds true regardless of how many times you sub-class Snow.

I would read up more on OOP.  Before you can "think in Java" you'll need to be able to think like an object oriented programmer.

A simple google search came up with these links:

http://staff.science.uva.nl/~heck/JAVAcourse/ch3/s1.html

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-21/lectures/inheritancei/lecture.html

Hope this helped.  Good luck!